# Make string array using file line input using methods

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, input

I am writing a code that reads a txt file line by line and stores each line as a string in an array using a method.

This is the contents of the txt file:

```
04/26/16    Sega 3D Classics Collection
07/14/16    Batman: Arkham Underworld
06/24/16    Tokyo Mirage Sessions #FE
```

The problem with my code is that the debugger gives me messages that I cannot change a file type to a string type. I am unsure on how to convert the contents of the txt file to become string values.

This is the code I have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
  public static void main (String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File file = new File("releasedates.txt");

    input(file);

  }

  public static String[]input (String file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[]arr = new String[3];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      arr[i] = sc.nextLine();

    }

    return arr;
    
  }

}
```

Comment: You pass an instance of File, but your method expects an instance of String as a parameter, the error message is spot on

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File file = new File("releasedates.txt");
    input(file);
  }
```

Here you call the input method. As you can see, you pass an instance of the File class as parameter.

```
public static String[]input (String file) throws FileNotFoundException
```

This is the signature of your input method, it accepts an instance of String, not of File.

Since the param is being used to instance a Scanner, and there is a Scanner constructor taking an instance of File, the best way to handle this, is to change the signature of your method to:

```
public static String[]input (File file) throws FileNotFoundException
```